# TypeError: ethers.provider.getStorageAt is not a function

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have deployed the contract and I'm trying to get the address at each storage slot

```
module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    log("----------------------------------------------------")
    log("Deploying FunWithStorage and waiting for confirmations...")
    const funWithStorage = await deploy("FunWithStorage", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [],
        log: true,
        // we need to wait if on a live network so we can verify properly
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })
    
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        await verify(funWithStorage.address, [])
    }

    log("Logging storage...")
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        log(
            `Location ${i}: ${await ethers.provider.getStorageAt(
                funWithStorage.address,
                i
            )}`

        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ethers V6 it's now getStorage

```
await provider.getStorage(address, slot);
```

Check out this documentation for reference https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#Provider-getStorage

Comment: Thanks Zartaj , its working ..

Comment: Awesome, you can checkmark the answer :)